# GUI equivalent for ffmpeg eq filter parameters

Tags: video, ffmpeg, filter

I was wanting to know if anyone is aware of a GUI tool that mimics or is similar to the eq video filter parameters in ffmpeg.  The [eq filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) is used to set brightness, contrast, saturation, gamma, etc.

I have a general sense of the parameters and how to control them at the command line...however, sometimes having a GUI-equivalent for such a tool can more easily/quickly allow for fine tuning or adjustments to the 8+ "knobs and switches" for ffmpeg's eq video filter.

I did find a plugin that's installed as part of Avidemux that's pretty close to ffmpeg's eq filter -- in Avidemux it's called [MPlayer eq2](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:video_filter_mplayer_eq2) --  but the results displayed in the preview window in Avidemux don't match the results I get when I transfer the syntax over to ffmpeg.

Does anyone have any pointers or ideas as to how to more easily manage changing the various eq parameters in ffmpeg?

Thanks!

Comment: Heh. ffmpeg's eq is a port of mplayer's eq2. I suspect the differences are due to interpretation of the color properties.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a difference in how they were implemented.  I didn't know if there was some type of ratio between min/max/default values of each of the parameters between ffmpeg's vs. Avidemux's implementation of that filter.

...thought about creating some formulas in Excel to do the ratio calculations and then build the eq expression that I would paste in for the ffmpeg command.  Sounds like a bunch of hoop jumping though.  I really would just like to have a GUI where I could toggle options at will and quickly preview.